# Android Studio - ¿Por qué la propiedad elevation no funciona?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Descripción:**

La propiedad xml "elevation" la vengo usando por bastante tiempo y hay algunas veces en las que con algunas vistas no me funciona y no sé por que.

**Problema:**

Ahora me está pasando que no funciona con una **AppBarLayout** a la cual le estoy asignando dicha propiedad.

**Adjunto el código XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:elevation="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relative_img_materia">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                app:elevation="10dp"
                android:background="#8d6e63"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**Gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

No funciona el definir la elevación directamente a tu `AppBarLayout`, Revisa la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45703684/250260) de [@KeLiuyue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6852729/keliuyue)

Especifica que debes crear un selector en un archivo dentro del directorio `/animator/`,  `/animator/appbar_elevation.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1"
        android:propertyName="elevation"
        android:valueTo="2dp"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
</item>
</selector>
```

y este selector definirlo a tu `AppBarLayout` :

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:elevation="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

            android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_elevation"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relative_img_materia">
```

Comment: Cual es el directorio animator? Me dirías como llegar o crearlo? Si se refiere a "anim" de las animaciones entonces decirte que intenté crear el archivo xml que me pasaste y por alguna razón no se reconoce el "selector".